# Make font-awesome icon on button not clickable

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, font-awesome

I have a bootstrap button with a font-awesome icon on it.

```
<button type="button" class="btn pull-right rotate-picture-right" aria-label="Rotate" id="picture{{ picture.pk }}">
            <i class="fa fa-repeat"  id="testright" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </button>
```

My on-click event:

```
$(document).on('click', '.rotate-picture-right', function (e) {
  rotate_and_reload(e, "right");
});
```

The function:

```
function rotate_and_reload(e, direction){
    var picture_id = e.target.id.replace("picture", "")
    var url = "{% url "device-api-picture-rotate" device.pk 0 "placeholder" %}".replace("pictures/0", "pictures/"+picture_id).replace("placeholder", direction)
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'PATCH',
        success: function() {
          var d = new Date();
          img = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
          if (img.src.includes("?")){
            img.src = img.src.split("?")[0] + '?' + d.getTime();
          } else {
            img.src = img.src + '?' + d.getTime();
          }

        },
    });
}
```

In Firefox, it doesn't make any difference whether I click on the icon or on the button, the on click event is triggered for the button.
In Chrome however, it is also possible to click on the icon and as I am using several properties of the buttons data, my function fails if I only get the icons information.
Is there a way to "disable" the icon and only make it be there and be pretty but not be able to trigger anything?

Comment: Tried `pointer-events: none`?

Comment: would I just put that in the class definition?

Comment: @LizzAlice I don't think this should be a problem, unless there's a click handler on `#testright`. Can you add relevant JS code to the question, in order to show the problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use CSS to disable pointer events on the icon.

```html
<button type="button" class="btn pull-right rotate-picture-right" aria-label="Rotate" id="picture{{ picture.pk }}">
            <i class="fa fa-repeat" style="pointer-events:none" id="testright" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </button>
```

However, a better way to handle this would be to ensure that the `event.target` is the same as the `event.currentTarget` in your click event handler. You can always get the reference of the button and not the icon by looking at the `event.currentTarget` property. The property name might be different based on whether you are using vanilla JS or a framework like jQuery.

Sample:

```js
$('button').click(function(e) {
    console.log(e.currentTarget); // This will be the button even if you click the icon
  })
```

Handy reference for different [Event Targets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Comparison_of_Event_Targets)

Comment: regarding the target... I tried getting the parents target by using e.target.parentElement.target, but that returned undefined...

Comment: `e.target` will give you the element that triggered the event. `e.delegateTarget` will give you the button (the element on which the handler was actually registered on)

Comment: Ok, I'll know that for next time, this time I will go with the CSS solution I think  :)

Comment: Use `e.currentTarget`. Do not use `delegateTarget` which is not valid (literally not even documented in JavaScript/HTML specs). So to summarize: `e.target` = the item that was clicked (started the event, such as the `<i>` icon inside the button), `e.currentTarget` = the object that has the registered event handler (such as the button itself). And lastly I will say it again: `e.delegateTarget` = invalid HTML/JS, do not use it. It actually comes from jQuery, and is therefore not a universal recommendation.